# Issue with Check box update or Edit to database in Codeigniter

Tags: database, codeigniter, insert-update

My function is when I will check then 1 will insert and if not then by default the field will fill with 0.At the time of **insert** problem is not happen, it store '1' to db but at the time of update with check box it not able to send '1' again to db,  it sending 0.

***AT THE INSERT TIME***

**View**

```html
.
```

```html
<?php echo form_checkbox("feature_opd","1", set_checkbox("feature_opd","1")); ?>

<?php echo form_checkbox("feature_gyane","1", set_checkbox("feature_gyane","1")); ?>

<?php echo form_checkbox("feature_iui","1", set_checkbox("feature_iui","1")); ?>
```

**Model**

```html
public function add_article($array) 
 {
  return $this->db->insert('table_name',$array);
 }
```

***AT THE UPDATE TIME***

**View**

```html
<div>
<?php 
if($article->feature_opd == 1)
{?>
<input type="checkbox" name="feature_opd" checked >
<?php
}
else
{?>
<input type="checkbox" name="feature_opd" >
<?php
}
?>
</div>

<div>
<?php 
if($article->feature_gyane == 1)
{?>
<input type="checkbox" name="feature_gyane" checked>
<?php
}
else
{?>
<input type="checkbox" name="feature_gyane" >
<?php
}
?>
</div>
<div>
<?php 
if($article->feature_iui == 1)
{?>
<input type="checkbox" name="feature_iui" checked>
<?php
}
else
 {?>
<input type="checkbox" name="feature_iui" >
<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

**Model**

```html
public function update_article($article_id , array $article)   
 {
  return $this->db
     ->where('id',$article_id)
     ->update('ivf_productsettings', $article );
 }
```

**My Query**  is how I will update db with check box. I am facing problem to update with check box in Codeigniter, Please suggest me , if my code going to tough then please suggest me in simple way how to update with check box in codeigniter .I am new in ci .

Comment: Can you confirm that at the time of update your check boxes are checked ?

Comment: no sir . blank input is going to bd

Comment: Just to clarify. You do this `if($article->feature_iui == 1)` and then it should be checked if the value is 1. Is it checked in the update view if the db value is 1? Then can you also do a print_r($_POST) in your update save controller and show me the results having checked the checkboxes. Also you are aware that checkboxes only send value of 1, they will never send 0... You have to manually put logic there for that.

Comment: It would also be wise to show the controller function that uses `update_article()` and the correct syntax for checked is not just `checked` but `checked="checked"` but I don't think that's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your update checkboxes like so:

```
<?php echo form_checkbox("feature_iui","1", set_checkbox("feature_iui","1", $article->feature_iui)); ?>
```

The default value will apply from the db.

Aside from that there is nothing aside from user input preventing the checkboxes from being properly sent. Thus, any code that is causing a 0 being put in the db is probably due to how you are processing the checboxes in your controller update function. As I've said in the comments, checkboxes only submit 1's never 0's.